# How to scroll always on same offset?

Tags: javascript, scroll, titanium-mobile

I have a titanium scrollView. If i make scroll action, the content is moving depending on the force of my finger scroll action. I need to make it scroll for defined value always (i.e. 400 pixels). How can i realize this?

I've tried it with `$.scrollTo() and scrollingEnabled = false`, but it's really not so smoothy.

Any other proposals?

**ADDED**
[here is video of similar idea (sorry for quality)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2pM0zlVu-c&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a kind of scrollableView, but vertical (the user can pull the scrollView, if the pull is longer than a threshold, the scrollView switch to the next vertical view, if not, the scrollView returns to its current vertical view), you can do it by using the "scroll" and "dragend" events. Here's an example for a drag down, and a scrollView with two 400px views stacked vertically:

```
var scrollView.top = -400; //Size of the view
var threshold = -100; // Threshold to pull for changing view
var changingPageTriggered = false;
var pulling = false;
scrollView.addEventListener('scroll',function(e) {
    var offset = e.y;
    if (offset <= threshold && !pulling) {
        pulling = true;
        changingPageTriggered = true;
    } else {
        pulling = false;
        changingPageTriggered = false;
    }
});
scrollView.addEventListener('dragend',function(e) {
    if (pulling && changingPageTriggered) {
        changingPageTriggered = false;
        pulling = false;
        changePage()
    }
});
function changePage() {
    scrollView.scrollTo(0,-400)
    scrollView.top = 0
}
```

I used something similar in a project but I didn't try the code above. You'll need to tweak it and add support for the drag up, it should get you started.

Comment: it's not exactly the same. I have horizontal view with 50 views on it and i want by slide move to next view and not to pass several

Comment: From your video it seems like a Coverflow. I never worked with one, but you might want to try [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.CoverFlowView)

Comment: it was nice to know this! =) so the question now, how to make something similar for android? i've found one html/js solution, but it's rather slow [link]http://www.elated.com/articles/cover-flow-remade-with-css-and-jquery/